# How to fix the" Your account is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok agent session" Ngrok error?

Tags: ngrok

When I start `ngrok` the following error displayed:

> ERROR:  Your account is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok agent session.
> ERROR:  You can run multiple tunnels on a single agent session using a
> configuration file. ERROR:  To learn more, see
> https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/config/ ERROR: ERROR:  Active ngrok
> agent sessions in region 'eu': ERROR:    -
> ts_2QsQSiaiyzbTv55hqqZSM9qpWWw (196.190.97.29) ERROR: ERROR:
> ERR_NGROK_108

I want to use ngrok to share my local file to my friends. I have used it before, but now it displays `ERR_NGROK_108`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following command:

`taskkill /f /im ngrok.exe`